# Знаки препинания

Tags: орфография, пунктуация

*Ему так долго и почти (не) двусмысмен_о  нам_кали  о необх_димости оставить к_мпанию в покое что он дог_дался наконец и уш_л  по английски правда из озорства пр_хватив с собой золочён_ую суповую ложку которую он возвр_тил (на) утро хозяйке и тут (же) к всеобщему уд_влению был прощён.*

Требуется расставить знаки препинания и пропущенные буквы.
По возможности объясните постановку той или иной запятой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Ему так долго и почти недвусмысленно намекали о необходимости оставить компанию в покое,*** (отделяет придаточное) ***что он догадался наконец и ушёл по-английски, правда из озорства прихватив с собой золочёную суповую ложку,*** (начало придаточного) ***которую он возвратил наутро хозяйке,*** (конец придаточного) ***и тут же, к всеобщему удивлению,*** (обособлено вводное сочетание) ***был прощён.***

Наконец — не вводное, т.к. можно заменить на НАКОНЕЦ-ТО; это обстоятельство.

Правда — вводное, стоит в начале обособленного деепричастного оборота; не отделяется от оборота.

Comment: Есть такое правило про вводное слово в начале деепричастного оборота?
Мне хочется поставить здесь запятую.

Comment: По Розенталю: если вводное слово стоит в начале или в конце обособленного оборота, то никаким знаком от оборота оно не отделяется; если же вводное слово стоит в середине обособленного оборота, то оно выделяется запятыми. Например:
 А Петр Петрович, по крайней мере по многим признакам, человек весьма почтенный (Достоевский); Среди товарищей есть эдакие поэты, лирики что ли, проповедники любви к людям (Горький); Женщина, веснушчатая, рыжая, похожая на кукушку, видимо его жена, все время истерически выкрикивала (Панферов); Посреди поляны росло большое дерево, судя по всему вяз.

Comment: Но если "возвратил" И "был прощён" однородные сказуемые, почему оборвалось придаточное? 
Или союз "которую" не позволяет убрать запятую после "хозяйке" ?
Меня смущает эта запятая.
Вот например.    Он ложку возвратил и сразу был прощён. (без зпт.?).
Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: он догадался наконец и ушёл по-английски, ... прихватив с собой ... ложку, которую он возвратил наутро хозяйке, и тут же, к всеобщему удивлению, был прощён.
Главное предложение: он догадался и ушёл и тут же был прощён, но между однородными сказуемыми есть придаточное предложение "которую он возвратил наутро хозяйке" - запятая закрывает придаточное, она необходима. Возвратил - из другого предложения, из придаточного, к однородным не относится.

Comment: Кстати,"и тут же был прощён" возможно разобрать как отдельное неполное предложение с пропуском подлежащего ОН. Но там и без того много оснований для постановки запятой: д/п оборот, придаточное.

Comment: Людмила, а что за прием с заменой "наконец" на "наконец-то"?
Я почему-то склонен видеть здесь именно вводное слово со всеми вытекающими запятыми.  
Объяснить не могу, могу только сослаться на грамоту, где подтверждается, что вопрос этот не совсем тривиален.

http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_436

ЗЫ Остальное не подвергаю ни малейшему сомнению.

Comment: Это действительно методический приём для разграничения наречия и вводного слова: наконец является вводным, если
1. завершает перечисление событий, фактов. Часто перед ним мы встречаем ряд однородных членов.
2. Выражает раздражение, нетерпение.Да когда ж ты, наконец, замолчишь?
Не является вводным, если имеет значение «под конец», «после всего», «напоследок».Тогда к слову наконец обычно можно добавить частицу -то – наконец-то. Если наконец – вводное слово, то такое добавление невозможно.
Долго мы говорили с ним, убеждали и наконец поняли, что он глух к любым доводам разума.

Comment: Есть здесь:http://gllagoll.narod.ru/vvsl.html
В нашем случае:Ему так долго намекали о необходимости оставить компанию в покое, что он догадался наконец(после всех намёков, наконец-то) и ушёл по-английски.-как раз этот случай.Перечисления фактов нет(порядка мыслей, тогда бы можно было подставить "и ещё"),чувств раздражения, нетерпения кого-либо нет, значит, не вводное